# Get App-Target(s) or Appname on CocoaPod post_install

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, post-install

Is there any way to access the apps target names (and NOT the pods target name) within the post_install cocoa-pods script?

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  pod '...'
end

post_install do |installer|
  # i need my application target 'MyProject' here
end
```